# Springboot Thymeleaf unable to find static resources when using multilevel path in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm using Springboot mvc with thymeleaf. I have a typical project structure.
It is able to load static resources when I'm mapping a simple path like `http://<context-url>/anything`
but it is not working when I'm using a multilevel path like `http://<context-url>/controllerpath/anything`.

Endpoint sample is below:
it is working

```
@GetMapping(path="/list")
    public ModelAndView getAdminList() {

        List<Admin> adminList = adminService.getAdminList();
        System.out.println(adminList);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home/main");
        mav.addObject("name", "Test");
        mav.addObject("list", adminList);
        return mav;
    }
```

but when I try to add something in `@Getmapping` path like

```
@GetMapping(path="/admin/list")
    public ModelAndView getAdminList() {

        List<Admin> adminList = adminService.getAdminList();
        System.out.println(adminList);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home/main");
        mav.addObject("name", "Test");
        mav.addObject("list", adminList);
        return mav;
    }
```

it loads the template but not static resources like js and css.

I tried to add `../` in template like

```
<link href="../dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

then it works, but I dont want to use `../` in my template.
Do we have any other configuration that can solve this issue.
TIA.

Comment: You need to use Thymeleaf style configuration `<link th:src="@{/dist/css/style.min.css} rel="stylesheet">` and `<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources you link in your template should not be relative to the current path. When you don't start your resources src/href path with a `/` they turn out to be relative URLs. Hence you need to specify the src/href path from the root starting with `/`.

So in your case, it would be: `/dist/css/style.min.css` and `/assets/libs/<file names>`.

Thymeleaf provides a handy feature to link the URLs in your application via the `@{}`. Using `@{}` will automatically prepend the context path (if there is any) to all the URLs. As mentioned in the comment by @Kedar so you would eventually end up with the following:

```
<link th:href="@{/dist/css/style.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```